# Angular Events Between Components

Tags: angular, events, components

I need to get an event from one component into another component lying next to the emitting one.

**HTML in DisplayComponent**

```
<app-header></app-header>   Emitting rom this ...

<show-list></show-list>     ... into this
```

**Code in header component**

```
@Output()
change: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();


public switchSomething():void {
  doSomething();
  this.change.emit();
}
```

Is there a propper way to do this or do I need any dirty workaround to achieve it. Maybe I just think just too complicated.

Comment: You can simply do it via a service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make app-header emit to DisplayComponent and have DisplayComponent call a function of show-list. I don't see any issue with your setup.

DisplayComponent html

```
<app-header (change)="doSomething($event)"></app-header>
<show-list #list></show-list>
```

DisplayComponent ts

```
@Component({etc.etc.})
export class etc etc. {

  @ViewChild('list') list: ShowListComponent;

  doSomething(event: Number) {
    this.list.callSomething(event);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes please, this is my first time working with events. I'm quitenew to programming :)